# Oracle SqlDeveloper JDK path

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have recently installed sqldeveloper but i'm getting the below warning window when I try to launch it. This is causing the sqldeveloper to run very very slow and it hangs frequently

[image]

I have tried editing the file sqldeveloper.cong as suggested in the window above but does not work

Original

SetJavaHome ../../jdk

Update 1

SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\ and all other variations but still getting the above warning window

Update 2
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin and all other variations

Please suggest the correct way

Comment: Do you have JDK installed at this location? `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60 ` ? If this so, update conf file, without /bin part and may be try to switch backslashes `\ ` to normal slashes `/` in path.

Answer (score 47):

The message seems to be out of date. In version 4 that setting exists in two files, and you need to change it in the other one, which is:

```
%APPDATA%\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf
```

Which you might need to expand to your actual `APPDATA`, which will be something like `C:\Users\cprasad\AppData\Roaming`. In that file you will see the `SetJavaHome` is currently going to be set to the path to your Java 1.8 location, so change that as you did in the `sqldeveloper.conf`:

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\
```

If the settig is blank (in both files, I think) then it should prompt you to pick the JDK location when you launch it, if you prefer.

Comment: %APPDATA%\sqldeveloper\goto this path as the version of your SQL Developer may vary then change the path as mentioned above. Worked for me thanks, @Alex Poole

Answer (score 19):

another thing you could try is to rename your **old** jdk folder, lets say its:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

change it to saomething like:

C:\Program Files\Java\xxxjdk1.7.0_04

Now, you should once again asked to set your jdk folder location on Oracle SqlDeveloper launch, and you can chose the right path.

Not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.

Milos

Comment: Agreed, not the most elegant but actually it worked for me as well! Thanks for sharing! +1

Answer (score 15):

In your SQL Developer Bin Folder find

```
\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf
```

It should be

```
SetJavaHome \path\to\jdk
```

You said it was `../../jdk` originally so you could ultimatey do 1 of two things:

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
```

This is assuming that you have JDK 1.7.60 installed in that directory; you don't want to point it to the `bin` folder you want the whole JDK folder.

***OR***

The second thing you can do is find the `jdk` folder in the sqldeveloper folder for me its `sqldeveloper\jdk` and copy and paste the contents from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60`. You then have to revert your change to read

```
SetJavaHome ../../jdk
```

in your sqldeveloper.conf

If all else fails you can always redownload the sqldeveloper that already contains the jdk7 all zipped up and ready for you to run at will: [Download SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt) The file I talk about is called `Windows 64-bit - zip file includes the JDK 7`

Answer (score 9):

I cannot believe Oracle's documentation is SO LAME! In some documents it is misleading people to point to the JDK by specifying the path to the JDK root, e.g. on a Mac:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/
```

Reviewing /Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh
revealed the method they use to set up the path:

> `TMP_PATH=`/usr/libexec/java_home -F -v 9
>   `if [ -z "$TMP_PATH" ] ; then
>     TMP_PATH=`/usr/libexec/java_home -F -v 1.8
>     `if [ -z "$TMP_PATH" ] ; then
>       osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "SQL Developer requires a minimum of Java 8. \nJava 8 can be downloaded from:\n http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/"'
>       exit 1
>     fi
>   fi`

Executing this manually from Terminal:

> /usr/libexec/java_home -F -v 1.8

Lists the path as:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And this is what you need to specify as the value for

> SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home

Thank you Oracle for wasting half a day on your "product" that does NOT even support your latest Java version, also released by you.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows,Close all the SQL Developer windows. Then You need to completely delete the **SQL Developer** and **sqldeveloper** folders located in user/AppData/Roaming. Finally, run the program, you will be prompted for new JDK.

*Note that AppData is a hidden folder.*

Comment: WARNING: This also **deletes all your saved connections**. Fixing `...\SQL Developer\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf` is much less painful.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use Mac, edit this file:

```
/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh
```

Mine had:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

and I changed it to 1.8 and it stopped complaining about java version.

Answer (score 0):

if you use sqldeveloper 18.2.0

```
edit %APPDATA%\sqldeveloper\18.2.0\product.conf
```

jdk9, jdk10, and jdk11 are not supported

change back to jdk 8

for example

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191-1
```