# java path of sqldeveloper in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have installed oracle-sqldeveloper on Ubuntu 14.04, but I gave the wrong java path during the installation (there 2 java on my PC), and oracle-sqldeveloper does not work because of java version. I uninstalled oracle-sqldeveloper, and I reinstalled again, but at this time it did not require the path, it use previous one. now, I want to change java path of installed oracle-sqldeveloper, help me

Answer (score 1):

Check you file

```
sqldeveloper_folder\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf
```

Inside you can see

```
SetJavaHome ../../jdk
```

Point in to whatever jdk you intent to use.

Comment: Depending on the version there may be two files to check. [This is for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24391298/266304); not sure what the Ubuntu paths will be.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out my post [here](https://dev.to/ishakantony/how-to-install-oracle-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-20-04-3jpd) on how to install Oracle SQL Developer on Ubuntu.

As for your question, u can try to uninstall your sqldeveloper and then delete your `$HOME/.sqldeveloper` directory and reinstall it, it will ask you for JDK path again