# Error while opening oracle-sqldeveloper

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i open oracle-sqldeveloper for it is asking for full pathname for java.exe.
I have installed a java and added the path like this

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin

But after adding the path i am getting the following.

[image]

Comment: It is asking for a J2SE SDK, and not the JRE. You need to install the JDK for it to work, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i open oracle-sqldeveloper for it is asking for full pathname for java.exe.

This is an issue with the missing JDK. *SQL Developer cannot run only with JRE*, it needs JDK for the debugger to work, something related to **Java Debug Wire Protocol**.

I think from **SQL Developer version 4** onwards, the **JDK** is embedded with the installation software. So, if you have downloaded the version 4 or up, you should be able to run it without additional installation of JDK, if prompted then provide the path to the embedded jdk.

Else, if your SQL Developer version is below 4, then you need to additionally download the jdk. See this download [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

The SQL Developer configuration file would be present at:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
```

Comment: [SQL Developer stores its own path to the JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24391298/266304), it doesn't rely on those settings. The issue here does seem to be JRE vs. JDK.

Comment: @AlexPoole You were right, re-reading the question and it is about missing JDK. Perhaps, OP's SQLDev version is below 4 and  thus JDK is not embedded in the installation software.