# Asking for Java path every time when launching SQLDeveloper

Tags: windows, oracle-sqldeveloper, windows-7-x64

Whenever I'm launching SQLDeveloper, I get prompted to enter Java path. Please see my `sqldeveloper.conf`:

```
IncludeConfFile ../../ide/bin/ide.conf

SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin

AddVMOption  -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true

AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false

AddVMOption -Dwindows.shell.font.languages=

AddVMOption  -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false  
IncludeConfFile  sqldeveloper-nondebug.conf

AddVMOption -Dide.noextensions=oracle.ide.webupdate
```

Am I missing anything here? Or additional configuration files, which needs to be change?

Comment: Not sure why it would keep prompting, but do you have [a product.conf file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24391298/266304) too?

Comment: I Think you should add java path in %PATH% variable. This may help you

Comment: @AlexPoole No. I didn't find that file. :(

Answer (score 2):

Beginning from version 4.0, sqldeveloper does not look into the `sqldeveloper.conf` file anymore.

Instead, it will look at the `product.conf` in your user directory. 
The path should be something like `C:\Users\jweawer\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\version\product.conf`.

Once you set `JAVA_HOME` in this file, you should no longer be prompted for this.

See more details here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/oracle-sql-developer-4-windows-and-the-jdk/.

Comment: Never knew that. After unzipping the new version I always edited `sqldeveloper.conf` and it worked. Today I started the new sqldeveloper install and when prompted entered a path to a JDK 11. That didn't work (some dll) and I had no clue how to correct the path. SQLDeveloper did not react on modifications of the `.conf` file. Your answer finally helped.